# Xcode 5 crash when Open storyboard made from Xcode 4.6

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, storyboard, xcode5

I'm working for a project with **Xcode 4.6** since 2 mounth ago, now that I want to send to apple my app everything is ok but when I've tried to run the app on **iOS 7** I saw some bugs; so I've downloaded the new **Xcode 5** for see where are the bugs, but what happened is that when I try to open the storyboard with IB *Xcode crash*. I try to see in Internet how fix this problem but I don't find anything about that.

Also the error that *Xcode* give me when i try to run the app on the *device* with *iOS 7* is:

```
CompileStoryboard YatchCo/en.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboard
    cd "/Volumes/Dati Lavoro/Mirko/Koffeecup/Y.CO"
    setenv IBSC_MINIMUM_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION 6.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --minimum-deployment-target 6.0 --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/iCreil/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/YachtCo.app/en.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboardc /Volumes/Dati\ Lavoro/Mirko/Koffeecup/Y.CO/YatchCo/en.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboard

2013-09-22 19:31:37.326 ibtoold[30327:707] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-4510/Framework/Document/Archiving/IBDocumentUnarchiver.m:216
Details:  Failed to unarchive an instance of NSFont
Object:   <IBDocumentUnarchiver: 0x7ffab98295e0>
Method:   -unarchiveObjectFromElement:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7ffab84191d0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010950ebdd -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1  0x000000010950e655 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010950e984 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x00000001088ecd88 __51-[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  4  0x00000001088eb026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  5  0x00000001088ec94d -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  6  0x00000001088ee0ce -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectArrayOrDictionaryFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  7  0x00000001088edb86 __55-[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveDictionaryFromElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  8  0x00000001088eb026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  9  0x00000001088ed7d4 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveDictionaryFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 10  0x00000001088ee814 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveDictionaryWithName:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 11  0x00000001088f2685 __77+[NSAttributedString(IBDocumentArchiving) instantiateWithDocumentUnarchiver:]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 12  0x00000001088eb026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 13  0x00000001088f1021 -[IBDocumentUnarchiverGroupMember(unarchiveContentWithBlock) unarchiveContentWithBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 14  0x00000001088f25f1 __77+[NSAttributedString(IBDocumentArchiving) instantiateWithDocumentUnarchiver:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 15  0x00000001088eef4f -[IBDocumentUnarchiver enumerateObjectMembers:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 16  0x00000001088f2496 +[NSAttributedString(IBDocumentArchiving) instantiateWithDocumentUnarchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 17  0x00000001088ecb02 __51-[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 18  0x00000001088eb026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 19  0x00000001088ec94d -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 20  0x00000001088ef179 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectForKey:defaultValue:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 21  0x000000010ed4fea1 IBUIAttributedTextContainerUnarchive (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 22  0x000000010ebe0d46 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 23  0x00000001088ecc6a __51-[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 24  0x00000001088eb026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 25  0x00000001088ec94d -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 26  0x00000001088ee0ce -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectArrayOrDictionaryFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 27  0x00000001088ed543 __50-[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveArrayFromElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 28  0x00000001088eb026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 29  0x00000001088ed2b8 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveArrayFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 30  0x00000001088ef328 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveArrayWithName:forOptionalKey:defaultValue:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 31  0x000000010867aa24 -[NSView(IBDocumentArchivingGenerator) unarchiveWithDocumentUnarchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 32  0x000000010ebe18a1 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 33  0x00000001088ecc6a __51-[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 34  0x00000001088eb026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 35  0x00000001088ec94d -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 36  0x00000001088ee0ce -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectArrayOrDictionaryFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 37  0x00000001088ed543 __50-[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveArrayFromElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 38  0x00000001088eb026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 39  0x00000001088ed2b8 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveArrayFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 40  0x00000001088ef328 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveArrayWithName:forOptionalKey:defaultValue:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 41  0x000000010867aa24 -[NSView(IBDocumentArchivingGenerator) unarchiveWithDocumentUnarchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 42  0x000000010ebe18a1 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 43  0x00000001088ecc6a __51-[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 44  0x00000001088eb026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 45  0x00000001088ec94d -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 46  0x00000001088ef179 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectForKey:defaultValue:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 47  0x000000010ebe258b (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 48  0x00000001088ecc6a __51-[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 49  0x00000001088eb026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 50  0x00000001088ec94d -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 51  0x00000001088ee0ce -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveObjectArrayOrDictionaryFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 52  0x00000001088ed543 __50-[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveArrayFromElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 53  0x00000001088eb026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 54  0x00000001088ed2b8 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveArrayFromElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 55  0x00000001088ee789 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveArrayWithName:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 56  0x000000010ecf9172 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 57  0x00000001088eb026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 58  0x00000001088f1021 -[IBDocumentUnarchiverGroupMember(unarchiveContentWithBlock) unarchiveContentWithBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 59  0x000000010ecf8fbb (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 60  0x00000001088eed39 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver enumerateGroupMembers:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 61  0x000000010ecf8e93 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 62  0x00000001088eb026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 63  0x00000001088eeb23 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver enterGroupWithName:optionalKey:usingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 64  0x000000010ecf8df0 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 65  0x0000000108690feb -[IBDocument unarchiveDocument:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 66  0x000000010ecf966e (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 67  0x00000001088eb026 -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 68  0x00000001088eb28b -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveDocument:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 69  0x00000001086895d3 __81-[IBDocument decodeContentFileWrapper:fileDataType:typeName:decodingStyle:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 70  0x00000001086bdb14 -[IBDocument runBlockInNewArbitrationStackEntryWithBehavior:block:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 71  0x00000001086892c8 -[IBDocument decodeContentFileWrapper:fileDataType:typeName:decodingStyle:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 72  0x0000000108689835 -[IBDocument readFromFileWrapper:ofType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 73  0x00007fff8f4ef527 -[NSDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:] (in AppKit)
 74  0x0000000108681110 __39-[IBDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 75  0x00000001086b5612 -[IBDocument invokeWithUndoSuppressed:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 76  0x0000000108680e5f -[IBDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 77  0x0000000108482712 (in ibtoold)
 78  0x000000010847e1e0 (in ibtoold)
 79  0x0000000108483c21 (in ibtoold)
 80  0x000000010848e23d (in ibtoold)
 81  0x000000010848e781 (in ibtoold)
 82  0x000000010848e654 (in ibtoold)
 83  0x000000010848cade (in ibtoold)
 84  0x000000010848deb2 (in ibtoold)
 85  0x000000010848d610 (in ibtoold)
 86  0x00007fff97e4d7e1 start (in libdyld.dylib)
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was that I work with 2 Mac in this project and in the *Mac* where I've installed **Xcode 5** I did't install the new font that I had in my project (and that i Used in the storyboard).

**So for fix the problem I've just installed the Fonts into the Mac where I get the problem**

I answer my question for help someone that will have my same problem!

Comment: I tried adding the custom font files. Still xcode crashes when i select storyboard. any idea ?

Comment: yes. When I try to run it, i get same error. When I select storyboard, it just crashes!

Comment: can you show me the error log? if you want you can open a new topic and link me it

Comment: You have to install the Fonts in your mac

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38981/discussion-between-mirko-catalano-and-sam)

Comment: Uninstalling the font and reinstalling it did the trick! thanks man!

Comment: I've filed a bug report on this (#15732525). Thanks for the solution!

Comment: My solution was to edit the storyboard XML in vim and temporarily remove calls to custom font and replace them with the SystemFont XML tag. You can find it usually in other places in the storyboard, and just copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 5 go to Preferences > Source Control > Uncheck the Enable Source control

Comment: thank you man! but I fixed the problem. I've just installed the new font and then everything work

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you build a xib file that has a custom font which is not installed on your build machine. See example below I'm using a custom font called **Source Sans Pro Bold** my UILabel.

[image: Using custom fonts in Interface Builder]

You need to install the custom fonts in your project on the machine that you are building. You can install them via Font Book or copy custom font files into `/Library/Fonts`.