# Storyboard not opening in Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, xcode6, uistoryboard

I developed an app for iPad using Xcode 5.1.1. The app worked perfectly fine. Now, since I have updated the Xcode to 6.0.1, the storyboard file isn't opening any more. On clicking the storyboard file from the project navigator, the Xcode keeps on loading the file and eventually everything stuck  since my mac's memory runs out (There are roughly about 20 VCs in my storyboard). When I tried to compile the project, Xcode kept on compiling the project and the build was never completed. I tried the project on Xcode 5.1.1 again and it worked perfectly fine. Since to upload app on app store, the IPA build should be from the latest version and side I have to support iOS 8, I can't work any more. Can anyone please guide me what the issue is?

PS:
[Xcode 5 crash when Open storyboard made from Xcode 4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946774/xcode-5-crash-when-open-storyboard-made-from-xcode-4-6)
I tried this as well, but since I am using Verdana font, I don't think this is the issue in my case.

Comment: Could you post your error that you get?

Comment: Also give a shot to this [reverting back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141112/reverting-all-xcode-settings-to-their-original-state) your xcode.

Comment: @walle84 Actually I am not getting any error. As I mentioned, the Xcode stuck on loading the storyboard.

Comment: so go for reverting your xcode and then try to open it.

Comment: @walle84 didn't work for me.

Comment: When you opened your project in xcode 6 then did you upgrade it ?

Comment: @walle84 don't remember it now. How can I check it now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62876/discussion-between-muhammad-jahanzaib-and-walle84).